# Getting ESOCKET error while connecting to SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server

Tried enabling SQL Server browser and also TCP, didn't solved the problem.

```
var sqlDb = require('mssql');

var config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'sa',
    server: 'ABHISHEK28069',
    database: 'Ultratech',
    port: 1433,
    };

exports.executeSql = function (sql, callback) {

    var conn = new sqlDb.ConnectionPool(config);
    conn.connect()
        .then(function () {
            var req = new sqlDb.Request(conn);
            req.query(sql)
                .then(function (recordset) {
                    callback(recordset);
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    callback(null, err);
                });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(null, err);
        })
};
```

Comment: Take a step back and use something other than node.js. How about testing a simple telnet/netcat connection to port 1433 of that server instead?

Comment: Tried using netstat, it is showing that sql server local address is 127.0.0.1:3213.

Comment: Tried telnet 127.0.0.1 1433 command, it is saying that couldn't open connection to host on port 1433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution, Forgot to restart the MSSQL service after enabling/starting TCP and MSSQL server browser services in configuration manager.

Comment: Mate, you saved me hours of running in circles :-D. Thank you! As supportive documenation, here how to enable TCP for MSSQL server: https://help.dugeo.com/m/Insight/l/438913-troubleshooting-enabling-tcp-ip-in-the-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

"ESOCKET" is actually the error "code", not the error message.  I had this issue and was also searching for "ESOCKET" error when I should have been looking for "ConnectionError".

For instance, one error I had was "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND" because apparently you must use "localhost" instead of the the "MACHINENAME\INSTANCENAME".

Later I had the same "ESCOCKET" code, but the connection error was for "self-signed certificate" because-unless you're on Azure or something-you must explicitly set "encrypt" to false.